# I am getting error while installing textract

Tags: python, python-3.x

Error Showing..

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 1671: character maps to

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At first, you are in MinGW shell, so you can't do C:\path\file, since bash interprets backslashes. You'd have to double them. Even if you'd do this, it would fail, since you have to specify the directory *containing* `setup.py`.

You firstly have to download EbookLib (version 0.15)
and edit the following text in `setup.py`:

```
    long_description = open('README.md').read(),
```

to this one:

```
    long_description = open('README.md', encoding="utf-8").read(),
```

Then run this in the directory of EbookLib:

```
pip install .
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been solved at `github`. steps and link for the solution is mentioned below:

First install **swig** from `conda`

```
conda install swig
```

downloaded the `EbookLib 0.15` zip from the releases

**https://github.com/aerkalov/ebooklib/releases**

unzip it,manually remove (with notepad++) the unicode char in the **README.md** file. `(unicode char is on Line 44)`

navigate to unzipped EbookLib 0.15 folder

```
cd to_unzipped_folder_path_here

pip install .
```

and finally

```
pip install textract
```